# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! Error

Tags: java, netbeans

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

The code I have is:

```
    public void getPlayerImage(){
    try {
          System.out.println("Somethings wrong if u dont see gay");
          up1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_up_1.png"));
          up2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_up_2.png"));
          down1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_down_1.png"));
          down2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_down_2.png"));
          left1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_left_1.png"));
          left2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_left_2.png"));
          right1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_right_1.png"));
          right2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_right_2.png"));
          System.out.println("Gay");
                  
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

I'm currently trying to make a 2D game application, and i've been fiddling with this code for hours, I'm somewhat new to Java and have no clue what i'm doing, now, im not sure but I think it could be because it's not a source package that the images are located in, yet I'm not sure how to do that (I'm using Netbeans IDE) Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I would call your resources directory 'images':
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)

Comment: I did, issue is that It won't fetch the image, I've tried images, res, resolutions, etc. and I cant find any fix, its just not fetching the image (I tested it by putting a print line)

Comment: Please post your full stack trace (*as code*). That vestigial error message doesn't seem to have much connection with the code you posted

Comment: @g00se The stack trace error message does have a connection to the code posted - it's coming from a call to `ImageIO.read()`.

Comment: @LukasHaberly [Have a look at these SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22java.lang.IllegalArgumentException%3A+input+%3D%3D+null%21%22+%22ImageIO.read%22), and their comments and answers, for problems similar to yours. If none of that helps, update your question to state what you tried that did not work. And regardless of that, update your question to show the stack trace. It would also be helpful if you identified the failing line in your code. It's probably (but not necessarily)  `up1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/player/boy_up_1.png"));`, right?